# Solr Error Instantiating Request Handler

Tags: tomcat, solr

Ok, I give up. I can't find a solution for this. Full story: I'm using ManifoldCF v.5.1 running on Jetty to connect to Opentext (everything works, I can crawl Opentext) and now I have Solr 4.0 Alpha running on tomcat 7 connected to take the output from ManifoldCF. However, as soon as ManifoldCF tries to hand off the data to Solr. I get this error:

```
SEVERE: null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: lazy loading error
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWra
ppedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:256)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handle
Request(RequestHandlers.java:238)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1561)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter
.java:442)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte
r.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:405)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
:269)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:515)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating Request Han
dler, org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler failed to inst
antiate org.apache.solr.request.SolrRequestHandler
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:434)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:477)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWra
ppedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:247)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.solr.handler.extractio
n.ExtractingRequestHandler
        at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
java:399)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:420)
        ... 21 more
```

I've tried several request handlers in solarconfig.xml they all fail the same way. I read that apache-solr-cell*.jar has to be in the solr.war but I can't seem to confirm that or incorporate it using ant. 
Please advise...

Comment: The answer is that Solr doesn't work because there's a bug in Tomcat 7.0.3. you need to use either tomcat6 or tomcat7 v7.0.5 or greater. click on the archive link under tomcat7 to see versions greater than 7.0.3

Comment: Okay I fixed it. I got solr 4.0 running in tomcat 7.0.8 by copying all of the manifoldcf jars into the webapps/solr/lib folder.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more what you have done? I have ExtractingRequestHanlder error every time I want to insert document into solr.

Comment: @FrenkyB: Hi, post your error in a new question and send the link here so I can find it easily and I'll take a look...

Comment: I've solved the problem with the help from this page: http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/if-you-want-to-configure-solr4.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to remove `startup="lazy"` attribute for this request handler?